Sub domain redirection issue for umbraco
I have created multiple Sites at root level and setup for all sub domain to respective sites.
Issue is that any of the subdomain page is working in main domain
Example:
Main Domain : XYZ.com
Sub Domain : ABC.XYZ.com/SubDomainPage
Sub domain page XYZ.com/SubDomainPage is working.
I want to restrict this link(XYZ.com/SubDomainPage) to page not found how can i do ?
I have setup the subdomain & maindomain in Culture and Hostnames.
Both domain & subdomain are setup in individual sites.

We have implemeted the umbraco version 8.7.0 .
